Structure of market for equity swaps (breakable vs non-breakable)
In the following answer to a question on breakable total return swaps , the answerer writes that:

As a general rule you will find that dealer-to-dealer trades are locked and customer-to-dealer trades are fully breakable.

Does anybody know any source for this claim?
Data on equity swaps by trade features would also be welcomed if it supports the claim.

there is a break-fee (5bps-10bps) generally associated with it.
i believe it's more related to a "Sourcing" type equity swaps. Where you are long on synthetic position a basket of stocks which the banks can rehypothecate to the BRM desk
for example, u are long some CHINA-A shares that are deemed "HOT" which the securities lending guys then lend out as locates for the other swap client to short-sell (note to the stock exchange it's a LONG-SELL) and since it's marked as long-sell the tick-rule doesn't apply meaning the electronic trading algo can cross the spread more often if needed)
so breakable would mean that the locates shown out isn't "stable" and have high recall risk. High recall risk would translate into a lower borrow rate for the borrower which mean the banks make less on the fees.
but there is a risk for breakable coming from inventory aspect when u need to unwind your sourcing trade during intra-day without prior notice. Swap desk doesn't have the shares to sell out.
There is the concept of synthetic fill-engine which is a software-computed way of working out the theoretical fill-prices for your sourcing trade unwind.

Although this does not directly address the question, it is very interesting, thank you. Can you clarify what a "long-sell" is? Where does the recall risk come from here; is your long exposure to China-A shares coming from a breakable swap in your example?

Been long on swap means i own the shares "synthetically", which means to unwind i should long-sell to close that.
BO=BUY_OPEN | SC=SELL-COVER (i.e. long sell) | SO=SELL_OPEN | BC=BUY_COVER
